# How to grep a directory for a string, rewrite it to something else and save in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a bash script that does the following:

- Removes a CSS directory
- Copies over new SASS from source
- Runs gulp task to generate CSS again

After I copy the SASS over, I would like to do the following before generating CSS again:

Find any occurrence of `('/assets` and change it to `('/themes/custom/mytheme/assets` in any of the files in the SASS directory.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Some simple `awk` / `sed` could easily do that

Comment: Better replace the text in the SASS source with a variable and let SASS do the substitution...

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned, this can be done for example with a basic `sed` substitution. The only thing to look out for, is to escape the slashes and to use `-i` to edit files in place.

`sed -i "s/('\/assets/('\/themes\/custom\/mytheme\/assets/" /path/to/SASS/*`